# How to avoid floating point error calculate average value in postgres db and get it in java application?

Tags: java, postgresql, floating-point, precision

I have the problem that I want to build an average over 6 values on the postgres 9.6 database that should lead to the result 5.0 but will be in my java application 4.99999999.

**Create the sql table and the values:**

```
CREATE TABLE mytesttable(
    value double precision
);
INSERT INTO mytesttable (value)
    VALUES (5),
    (5.1),
    (5.3),
    (5),
    (5.4),
    (4.2)
;
```

Now if you process in pgAdminIII the following **SELECT-statement** it returns a correct 5 in the gui:

```
SELECT AVG(value) AS value_avg FROM mytesttable;
```

But in Java it will be 4.9999.... I use the following **postgres jdbc driver**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.1212</version>
</dependency>
```

To get the average from the database I create a session and execute the statement as you can see here in **my java code**:

```
Class.forName(driver);
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, password);
String sql = "SELECT AVG(value) AS value_avg FROM mytesttable";

Statement statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs.next()) {
    Double doubleValue = rs.getDouble("value_avg");
    System.out.println("own table - double-value: "+doubleValue);
                
    String doubleString = rs.getString("value_avg");
    System.out.println("own table - string-value: "+doubleString);
                
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = rs.getBigDecimal("value_avg");
    System.out.println("own table - bigdecimal-value: "+bigDecimal);
}
```

The **result** of this printet **in the console** of java is that:

> own table - double-value: 4.999999999999999
>
> own table - string-value: 4.9999999999999991
>
> own table - bigdecimal-value: 4.9999999999999991

As you can see I tried also to retrieve the values as BigDecimal and also as String - not works.
**Anybody has an idea how I can avoid this floating point error?**

Comment: From what I recall, this is a known problem when dealing with floating point numbers, there may be small rounding errors etc.  Do you really plan to report those numbers to 16 decimal places?  Note that even at 10 decimal places, your Java code is still reporting `5.0000000000` as the answer and there is no problem.

Comment: Even something as benign as System.out.println(1 - 0.1 - 0.1 - 0.1) will already display rounding errors (0.7000000000000001 on my machine).

Comment: No I don't need so many decimal places. But I don't want to think about rounding or truncing. I think if the avg-result is an exact 5 it should be possible to deliver that to an output stream (e.g. System.out.println()). @JacoVanNiekerk: You example works with BigDecimal: BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(1).subtract(new BigDecimal(0.1)).subtract(new BigDecimal(0.1)).subtract(new BigDecimal(0.1));
  System.out.println(bd.doubleValue());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of changing the SQL statement, you may consider showing less digits on the Java side, if the value is just used for presentation.

```
double doubleValue = rs.getDouble("value_avg");
System.out.format("own table - double-value: %.4f", doubleValue);
// should print `5.0000`.
```

---

The floating point error originates from PostgreSQL, so there is no use increasing the precision on Java side. Although you may see "5" coming out from the SELECT statement, the fact is your PostgreSQL client does not show all digits of the result.

You can cast the numbers to the [`numeric` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) to get fixed-point arithmetic.

> The type `numeric` can store numbers with a very large number of digits and perform calculations exactly. It is especially recommended for storing monetary amounts and other quantities where exactness is required. However, arithmetic on `numeric` values is very slow compared to the integer types, or to the floating-point types described in the next section.

The first 3 columns below shows that the average is indeed imprecise on the PostgreSQL side. The last 3 columns shows computation using fixed-point calculation instead of floating point (You might want to change the `numeric(4, 2)` to increase precision).

```sql
SELECT
    avg(n),  -- 5
    avg(n) = 5,  -- false
    avg(n) - floor(avg(n)),  -- 0.999999999999999
    avg(n :: numeric(4, 2)), -- 5
    avg(n :: numeric(4, 2)) = 5,   -- true
    avg(n :: numeric(4, 2)) - floor(avg(n :: numeric(4, 2)))  -- 0
FROM (VALUES 
    (5 :: double precision),
    (5.1 :: double precision),
    (5.3 :: double precision),
    (5 :: double precision),
    (5.4 :: double precision),
    (4.2 :: double precision)
) t(n)
```

Comment: thank you very much for this great answer. Especially the last part was important for me to understand. I don't really want to format my values at java side and I don't want to change my datatype (from double precision to numeric) in the database. I will think more about it (and will mark your answer as correct later)

Comment: After think about it, I think it is a good solution to cast them into numeric like: `String sql = "SELECT AVG(value)::numeric AS value_avg FROM mytesttable";`. So I not must change my data types of columns. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

All numerical operations on floating point values are inexact.

The reason that you don't notice that normally is that PostgreSQL, when it converts a `real` or `double precision` value to text, rounds after a certain number of digits, so that the result is the same on all platforms.

This is controlled by the parameter [`extra_float_digits`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-EXTRA-FLOAT-DIGITS). If you increase that parameter from its default value of 0 (the maximum is 3), you'll get more digits, which will cause the text representation to be more accurate, but will show the rounding errors:

```
SET extra_float_digits=3;

SELECT AVG(value) AS value_avg FROM mytesttable;
      value_avg
---------------------
 4.99999999999999911
(1 row)
```

Or even more surprising:

```
SELECT 0.3::double precision;
        float8
----------------------
 0.299999999999999989
(1 row)
```

Now the PostgreSQL JDBC driver sets `extra_float_digits` to 2 or 3 to avoid losing any precision, which can cause the effects you observe.

If you don't care for those extra digits and would rather have a nice round value, change `extra_float_digits` back to 0:

```
conn.createStatement().execute("SET extra_float_digits=0");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a solution that works too. After thinking about it, I decide to use the numeric-cast that kennytm explains in his answer. So I avoid a proprietary "pre-query" to the database.